# How do I insert content to DIV on the top of existing content using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Using the `.append()` function inserts content at the bottom. How to add to the top of the existing content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)